# What is the definition of homotopy flat connections?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, connections, curvature, differential-graded-algebras

What is a definition of a homotopy flat connection - in the context of differential forms with values in a dg algebra

Comment: Could you give a reference where such an object is referred to, or elaborate a bit on what you might expect from such a definition?

Comment: I think, it should be *"homotopy flat" connection*.

Comment: One possible definition (which yields an ∞-Riemann–Hilbert correspondence) is in Block and Smith's paper [A Riemann--Hilbert correspondence for infinity local systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.2843v5)

Comment: Andy, It's precisely because I'd like to cite it if it exists,

Answer (score 1):

One place where this notion appears (without a formal definition) is in a remark after Corollary 4 in

*Cohen, Ralph L.; Stacey, Andrew*, [**Fourier decompositions of Loop bundles**](http://www.arxiv.org/abs/math/0210351), Goerss, Paul (ed.) et al., Homotopy theory: relations with algebraic geometry, group cohomology, and algebraic (K)-theory. Papers from the international conference on algebraic topology, Northwestern University, Evanston, IL, USA, March 24–28, 2002. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). Contemporary Mathematics 346, 85-95 (2004). [ZBL1068.55016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1068.55016).

> Remark. The homotopy type of the map of based loop spaces, $\Omega f_\zeta: \Omega M \to U(n)$ can be obtained by taking the holonomy map of a connection on $\zeta$. Therefore this corollary can be interpreted as saying that in order for $L\zeta$ to have a Fourier decomposition, $\zeta$ must admit
> a “homotopy flat” connection.

Deciphering what they are saying, my guess is that a collection $\nabla$ on a  (say) principal $G$-bundle $P\to B$  with simply-connected base $B$ is **homotopy flat** if the holonomy map
$$
\Omega(M)\to G 
$$
is null-homotopic. (In the case of a flat bundles this map is, of course, constant.) Maybe one of the authors, Andrew Stacey (@user:45) can confirm (or deny) that this is what they meant.

Comment: I always thought that in the flat case, the holonomy map $\Omega M \to G$ should factor as $\Omega M \to \pi_1(M) \to G$, where the first map is obtained by taking $\pi_0$ and the second is a homomorphism. Equivalently, it is locally constant.

Comment: @JohnKlein: In the answer I was explicitly assuming (as the authors of the quoted paper) that the base is simply-connected. Otherwise, the right thing to do is to restrict to null-homotopic loops or work in the universal covering space.